# Fitting ARMA-GARCH with t-distributed error

Tags: time-series, arima, likelihood, garch, t-distribution

I am currently trying to find parameter estimates to a ARMA-GARCH model with student's t distributed innovations.
However, the errors are t-distributed so there are no closed form MLE. As for finding it, I would have to employ numerical methods.

My idea is to write out the PDF of the student's t and formulate it as a likelihood function,
then take the natural logarithm to get the log likelihood. Let's do this, consider the likelihood function of the student's t distribution.
$$
L(x;\nu)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\nu \pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)}\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{\nu}\right)^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}
$$
Taking the logarithm yields:
$$
logL(x;\nu)=log\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)\right)-log\left(\sqrt{\nu \pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right)\right)+log\left(\left(1+\frac{x^{2}}{\nu}\right)\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{\nu+1}{2}\right)
$$
The problem is now that I have  no way of representing the parameters of my ARMA-GARCH in this log-likelihood function, so how to I get the parameter estimates? Do I have to assume a non-central student's t-distribution to estimate the parameters or maybe even a Generalized T-distribution?

If I had the normal distributed errors I would try to represent my model with a design matrix, $X$, and a parameter vector as $\beta$ and use the formula
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty,
$$
where $y$ is my observations.